# How much wobble is too much?

Tags: wheels, repair

My back wheel has a really small wobble maybe a millimeter of movement if you push it sideways, it is barely noticeable but you can definitely feel it.  Should the wheel be completely solid or is a tiny wobble ok?  My front wheel has 0 wobble and feels different.

Comment: Just to clarify - when you spin the wheel on the bike, if it wobbles from side to side or up-down, it's out of true. You seem to be talking about something else, correct? I am fairly sure you are talking about not spinning the wheel and pushing laterally. If so, that could mean your bearing preload adjustment is wrong - preload is a term for how squished the bearings in the hubs are. Only some hubs allow you to adjust preload, though - if there's no adjustment, there shouldn't be any issues with play like this.

Comment: to add to Weiwen’s comment: For true-ness look at the rim while spinning, not a the tyre. Tyres sometimes have a bit of wobble due to manufacturing tolerances.

Answer (score 7):

Bearing play should be zero. Any more than that and you risk bearing damage, bad handling etc. It’s easiest to check by pushing the rim from side to side. If there is movement without any resistance it’s usually bearing play.

If you have quick release levers there can be a small amount of play with the wheel taken out, since closing the lever compresses the bearings slightly.

If you have cup&cone bearings you can adjust the play. With other bearing types you might have to replace the bearings completely.

Comment: "If you have quick release levers there can be a small amount of play with the wheel taken out, since closing the lever compresses the bearings slightly." I believe this statement is not true, if this is cone hub and it is properly tightened with 'contra' not on cone. if the play appears after QR released, it possibly lacks at least one nut.

Comment: I haven't had cup and cone hubs in a long time, but I believe the statement is actually true: I recall that you were supposed to adjust the hubs so that there was a bit of play off the bike, and zero play when you clamp them in the dropouts. This would only apply to hubs where you can adjust the preload (which I believe is all cup and cone hubs, and only some cartridge bearing hubs).

Comment: I’ve definitely had this experience with Shimano 105 hubs with cup&cone bearings. I’m fairly certain they were assembled correctly, tightened correctly and I didn’t use excessive force on the quick release lever or anything. On my Mavic Ksyrium Elite wheelset you can adjust the bearing play while the wheels are installed on the bike and I think Mavic actually listed that as an advantage.

Comment: If the axle and quick release are made of real, not infinitely rigid materials, closing the quick release stretches the skewer and compresses the axle. This tightens the bearings, and the adjustment without QR should accommodate for it.

Comment: So should I get it fixed asap?  I'm thinking of going to the shop Saturday so couple more days of commute.

Comment: @Michael Not to be pedantic, but I think the term in this case is preload, not play - preload is how much the bearings are getting squeezed laterally by a combination of the hub's adjustment mechanism and the QR. Of course, it's pretty likely that a shop employee would know what you're talking about in any case.

Comment: @ojs I don't think you are able to actually squeeze/compress the axle so much that you can actually cancel/reset noticeable play on the hub, especially using such flexible setup like QR rod with thin nuts. I'm open to being convinced with calculations.
What comes to my mind instead is that the hollow axle under pressure of QR may buckle and that way shorten order of magnitude more than shortening that comes from material elasticity under stress without permanent deformation.

Comment: @krzyski you really need to do the homework yourself. And please stop thinking without doing the math, especially if your thinking goes against common wisdom and several commenters' experience.

Comment: @ojs you are offensive without serious reason. I'm not disputing with the fact that closing QR may cancel the clearance. The thing is that I think about the _real_ cause of such behaviour.
e.g common knowledge says chain is prolonging because of stretching, which is not true.

Comment: @krzyski no reason to be offended. It's just that thinking about "real" causes without doing the math is a great way to mislead oneself. It's great that you know how chains elongate, though. Keep it up.

Answer (score 6):

If you can feel (or see the movement at the bearing cup) it's not really OK.
However, it may be that you need only tighten it up (depending upon the type of bearing).

Answer (score 5):

It is important to know from where the play comes. If this comes from the cone bearing clearance, then in general it is not good, it should not have play.
But, I personally think it is safer to have little play than have your hub screwed too tight. E.g. every time I buy platform pedals from the store, those are usually too tight.

First think to check is the condition of cone. When there are small traits of wear, the cone should be replaced, but sometimes in practice it doesn't need immediate replacement. Then, you have to take into account that celaranece may be uneven. You have to roll the wheel and check in multiple places and tighten no more than there is a position of the wheel that hub has no clereance. You should not screw more, even if you feel small clearance after spinning the wheel by some angle.

Re properly tightening, it is not trivial.

When you put a cone on the axle, please note it has forward-backward play and it is natural, as thread has some play to be able to put the nut on it. If you screw the cone towards the balls in bearing, that it has no play, then the inside cone threads lean on the "external" surfact of axle threading.
And then, when you tighten lock nut, even if you hold the cone with cone wrench, you push the cone towards ball bearing by thread thickness, 1mm or so (as a result locknut's internal threading lean on the opposite "slope" of the axle threading than the cone threading). And this makes hub being too tight. You should leave small play while putting cone, then adding lock nut, check for the play and if necessary, unscrew lock nut and screw cone forward/backward, if necessary. Repeat if needed multiple times for perfect adjustment.

Comment: Please read the comments about adjustment on the other answer.

Comment: “personally think it is safer to have little play than have your hub screwed too tight” I’d actually go the opposite way (but only ever so slightly). Ball bearings are made to run smoothly, even under heavy load. A tiny bit of preload won’t kill them. Especially for things like headset bearings where friction losses don’t matter.

Comment: Re headset bearings totally agree. It is clearance that kills them, that allow balls to punch the race/cup more than with too tight setup. Those are there just to allow angualr movement, not to endure millions of revolutions.

Comment: @Michael re ball bearings: let's consider ball bearings and cone hub separately. You wrote: "ball bearings are made to run smoothly, even under heavy load" which is true, but you cannot imply from that, that post-installation zero clearance is ok. All tech specs I know mention _working clearance_ being non-zero (eg  .00075 x diameter). I can imagine post-installation zero clearance in very very special case when calculated working conditions cause outer race to extend because of temp to catch some desired clearance.

Answer (score 2):

All existing materials, including the ones that used for wheelbuilding, are more or less elastic. Because of this, wheels or really any objects do have some flexibility. On bikes with multi-speed freewheels the rear wheel has narrower hub flange spacing, so the same lateral force turns into larger force on the spokes, making the rear wheel a bit more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

A millimeter is way too much for my taste.

On all bicycles, rim or disc brake, I true my wheels to have at most 0.5mm difference from too-far-in-the-left spots to too-far-in-the-right spots.

This means that if you imagine an "average rim position" plane, in the spots where the rim protrudes from this plane to the left most, it protrudes at most 0.25mm, and in the spots where the rim protrudes from this plane to the right most, it protrudes at most 0.25mm.

Another way to think about the limit (and how to measure it): if your truing stand has the gap between feeler screws be 24.0mm and the rim outer width is 23.5mm, and the wheel is rotating without the rim ever touching the feeler screws, you know the difference is at most 0.5mm, or in other words, the error is between +0.25mm and -0.25mm.

I also consider 0.4mm error in dishing the maximum. This means that if you put the dish checking stick to one side of the wheel an adjust the center bolt to touch the wheel hub axle end, and then move the dishing stick to the other side (with more axle protrusion), and touch the end of the axle and rim at one side, the rim at the other side has 4*0.4mm = 1.6mm gap at most.

Note that I could of course do a far better job with a very stiff truing stand and lots of time spent truing. My truing stand is the cheapest I found, very wobbly, and also I don't consider spending too many extra hours on wheel truing to be an investment that pays off.